# PHP academy tutorial - query method

Tags: php, mysql, sql, youtube

I recently started watching this serie of tutorials (http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc) and came across a problem writing the DB class.
It's in the 8th vid.

My query function doesn't seem to work well. I can successfuly connect to the database as the "connected" echo is displayed. But the success echo is never displayed..

DB.php :

```
<?php
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo, 
            $_query, 
            $_error = false, 
            $_results, 
            $_count = 0;

    private function __construct(){
        try{
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.config::get('mysql/host').';dbname='.config::get('mysql/db'), config::get('mysql/username'), config::get('mysql/password'));
            echo '->Connected'.'<br />';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());  
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()){
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)){
                foreach($params as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }
            if($this->_query->execute()){
                echo 'Success';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you spot my error ? Trying to find where my function doesn't work, I managed to understand that the first if statement of the query function is not verified..
In the index.php I use the same line as in the video :

```
DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?', array('alex'));
```

All databases and tables have been created successfuly. I can access and perform sql queries with a classic try catch bloc and query method.
What I especially don't understand is the first if statement condition in the query function.

Thank you for your time !!

Comment: You need to learn how to get error messages from MySQL. I'm sure that's in the tutorial somewhere.

Comment: The if statement is checking that `$this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)` succeeds

Answer (score 1):

Your PDO object gets stored in a local variable (`$db`) in the constructor. Assign it to the property (`$_pdo`) instead, because your `query()` method is calling `$this->_pdo->prepare()`.

```
$this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.config::get('mysql/host').';dbname='.config::get('mysql/db'), config::get('mysql/username'), config::get('mysql/password'));
```

Answer (score 0):

problem in __construct()

wronge   : _construct()

### right is :  __construct()

private function __construct() {
            try {
                $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.Config::get('mysql/host').';dbname='.Config::get('mysql/db'),
                        Config::get('mysql/username'),
                        Config::get('mysql/password')
                );
            echo 'connected';
                } catch(PDOException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
}

Answer (score -1):

Try copy/paste this.

```
    <?php
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo, $_query, $_error = FALSE, $_results, $_Count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this -> _pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . config::get('mysql/db'), config::get('mysql/username'), config::get('mysql/password'));
            echo "Conectat";
        } catch(PDOExeption $e) {
            die($e -> getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()){
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {                        
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)){
                foreach($params as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }            }
            if($this->_query->execute()){
                echo 'Success';
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: To make your answer better, you should explain what you changed and what was the error in the original code (that was the question, after all :) ). This way other users in the future could learn from this rather than fixing a specific user's problem.